# how we use BigInt?

Tags: java, database

this is my code but it givas an error would you please help me(in mySQL I have a table that has VARCHAR name ,VARCHAR address and VARCHAR telephone and TINYINT age and BIGINT charge)

I want to insert a name and address and telephone and age with calling this method .but it will give an error for line `insertARow("Adam Smit","21 First Avenue, Fairlyland, 87654","123456789",35);`
ERROR:create an InsertARow method(String,String,String,Int);

the class:

```
    insertARow("Adam Smit","21 First Avenue, Fairlyland, 87654","123456789",35);


}

private static void insertARow(String name,String address,String telephone,BigInt age) {

}
```

Comment: There is no Java type BigInt, except for sun.security.util but you should not use that. Do you use a 3rd party library?

Comment: @Arne: see http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

Comment: @Jim: I know BigInteger, but the compiler does not know BigInt.

Answer (score 5):

A [`BIGINT` in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html#id2812811) is a 64 bit integer type, so you can simply handle it as a `long` (and/or `Long`) value in Java, as long as you are using the `SIGNED` variant.

If you want to support an `UNSIGNED BIGINT`, then you will have to handle the values as [`java.math.BigInteger`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) in Java.

Since you don't show any code that actually interfaces with the Database (JDBC) I can't tell you what you're doing wrong.

Comment: there is not any difference between long or Long here? also it is unsigned.

Comment: There's no difference in the data range between `long` and `Long`. Of course there is the difference that one is a primitive type, while the other is a Wrapper class. But that's outside the scope of this question.

Comment: would you please help me that how can I send a BigInt age to the sql table (in my code)(I used the type of age as a BigInt!

Comment: You need to search online for a tutorial on JDBC.  Then paste the code that's failing to work along with any stack traces.

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem in [tag:scala] `java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.Integer is not a valid external type for schema of bigint`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is attempting to use BigInt as a Java type, which will not compile.  As Joachim mentions you need to use a `long` or `Long` in Java.